# How to query transactions for a particular resource in hyperledger sawtooth

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am doing multiple transactions like location update for an asset, and couldn't find any way to query the transactions based on that resource:

For example If I create an asset `fish1`, and then make transactions to update the location of the fish, now I want to fetch the transactions for the `fish1` so I can get a list of `geopoints` and plot them on the map.

If anyone has done something like this, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On-chain solutions**

There are two approaches depending on how you 'update' the location.

1. If you are updating information at the same address then you must take precaution to capture all the updates. This assumes the asset has a collection that it can add to at transaction time. Using this approach it would be simply a matter of fetching the address data (using `/state/` REST-API call) and splaying out the collection of data updates however you want.
2. On the other hand, if each update results in a new piece of data being added to the blockchain then you would be using some address scheme (I assume) where you can use a prefix in the '/state?address=xxx` call to collect all asset updates. You would probably want to also fetch the block to determine order unless the data at each address captures some kind of time information to sort on.

There are pros and cons using either approach of course.

**Off-chain solutions**

Sawtooth provides an Event registry where a client (of some kind) can register Event listeners to store data off-chain in any form the application requires. This is often suggested for solutions that have a broad/rich querying need as the sawtooth Merkle Trie (where blockchain data is stored) does not offer this flexibility.

Comment: Hi @Frank, the first solution is what I intend to do but adding too much data for the state doesn't seem right solution, is there any way I can query, or if there's any solution available for ledger sync with `mongodb`, please help me with that.

Comment: Thanks I synced the ledger with `mongodb` and now I'm querying with that. Please vote the question If you think It's worth.

Comment: Just in case, the REST API: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.1/rest_api/endpoint_specs.html , and two projects from sawtooth showing the off chain solution: https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/sawtooth-supply-chain , https://github.com/hyperledger/grid